# SQL count rows where column value contains string

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of rows where a certain column has a substring in the column value.

This doesn't work

```
select count(column_name like '%substring%') 
from table_name
```

Example: I want to count the rows including 'no'

```
column_name
-----------    
noa
noit 
yot
```

Expected result: 2

Because 'no' is a substring in 'noa' and 'noit'.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select sum(case when column_name like '%substring%' then 1 else 0 end)
from table_name ;
```

Or, if that is the only value you want, use filtering and `count(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from table_name
where column_name like '%substring%';
```

The first is more suitable when you have additional columns in the query.

I should note that the SQL standard has another method of accomplishing this, using `filter`:

```
select count(*) filter (where column_name like '%substring%')
from table_name ;
```

However, most databases do not support this syntax.